# How can i put the image in the section of table in the titleForHeaderInSection method?

Tags: iphone

i have so confused to make an image in the table's header section ,
and i have make put the image in the cell of table but i cannot understand how to make put image in the section part of table .
here is my code of that method ..

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  if (section == 0) {

//      return @"Alpahbets"; With String

```
    UILabel *alphabet = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
    alphabet.text = @"Alphabet";
    return alphabet.text;





} if (section == 1) {
```

//      return @"Roman"; with String
        UILabel *roman = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
        roman.text = @"Roman";
        return roman.text;

```
} else {

//  return @"Digits"; With String
    UILabel *digit = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
    digit.text = @"Digit";
    return digit.text;

}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong Delegate method. That delegate method, from the [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) only allows you to provide a new text string for the default section header types.

To add an image to the section headers you want to take a look at the [UITableViewDelete](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) methods

**Modifying the Header and Footer of Sections**
– tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
– tableView:viewForFooterInSection:
– tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:
– tableView:heightForFooterInSection:

Using these you can provide a new view (rather than just the text) for a header of a section.